# How to set cpu priority for ndk-build (on Windows)?

Tags: android, android-ndk, cpu-usage

I am working on a large C++ app for android and when building (ndk-build -j 4), I can't do almost anything on the PC, as compiler threads have same cpu priorities as apps.

Is there a way to tell ndk-build to run compiler processes with lower priorities? I am ok with build lasting 10-20 % longer if I can actually use the computer while building...

Thanks!

Comment: FWIW, this often has more to do with insufficient RAM than thread CPU priority.

Comment: Imo not in my case, I have several GB of free RAM when compiling (cca 400 MB of obj files and 12 GB RAM)

Answer (score 0):

Just set lower number to `-j` argument.

`ndk-build -j 3`